# How to set a field read only in rails 3.1.0 views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, simple-form

My question is how to set a field in rails form read only. The following is a selection box in quotes controller. Users are not allowed to change the selection.

```
  <% @quote.test_items.each do |t| %> 
    <%= f.association :test_items, :label => false, :selected => t.id %>
  <% end %>
```

The app uses simple_form. Thanks so much.

Comment: in rails 4+ there is readonly : true now. disabled: true also works

Answer (score 45):

I've encountered a similar problem, thankfully, there is a simple resolution.

The basic issue is that if you use `:disabled => true` with simple_form you will not see that value back in the controller. When you pass an object from HTML form to later bind it to the model - you need all of those attributes. The `:disabled => true` however does not pass any such attribute.

The solution to this is to use `:readonly => true` - it will protect the field from user entry and it will still pass the param value back to the controller so you can bind everything to your model.

Good luck.

See https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/pull/367

Comment: This answer is the most relevant to the question, IMO. Should be selected as correct.

Comment: I also found that associations may not respect the readonly flag and wound up using disabled for my needs

Answer (score 7):

I believe you'd just pass in `:disabled => true`. It's been my experience that options 'just work' with simple_form. So in your case:

```
<% @quote.test_items.each do |t| %> 
  <%= f.association :test_items, :label => false, :disabled => true, :selected => t.id %>
<% end %>
```

From the [simple_form github repo](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form):

It is also possible to give the :disabled option to SimpleForm, and it'll automatically mark the wrapper as disabled with a css class, so you can style labels, hints and other components inside the wrapper as well.

Comment: The :disabled => true greys out the selection and make the selection unchangeable. However it also does not allow the server retrieving the value of the selection. The app needs to pass the selection value to the server. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Clearly a form element is not what you are looking for since you want it disabled anyway. Are you trying to set default values for the form?

Comment: What we need first is a readonly field. The value of the field is carried over from database and no need for user to select. The app also allow user to delete a field completely. That's why we need the value to be sent to the server. :disabled => true accomplish the goal of readonly and failed on 2nd one which is to send the value to the server. if the disabled field can be set to false before posting to server, it may work.

Comment: So, here's what you should do - either: Set the value of the attribute in the controller before sending it to the view and then add a hidden field to the form, OR, set the attribute value in the controller once the form has been submitted. Does the user need to see this attribute at all?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, what @gk0r said, as it is [documented here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html):

NOTE: The `HTML` options `disabled`, `readonly`, and `multiple` can all be treated as booleans. So specifying `:disabled => true` will give `disabled="disabled"`.

*disabled will have slightly different behavior than readonly.

Answer (score 3):

The top answers above are all wrong.

disabled attribute has a different behaviour than readonly.

read and compare them:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp

Tip: Disabled  elements in a form will not be submitted.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp

The right answer is to use

```
:readonly => true
```

something like this:

```
<%= f.association :test_items, :label => false, :readonly => true, :selected => t.id %>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me if the association method accepts HTML options or not, but if it does, you can pass `disabled: 'disable'` to make it read-only with a fixed value.

I think you might be able to choose the fixed value by passing association as block, as shown in the association docs:

```
f.association :company do |c|
  c.input :name, selected: 'selection'
  c.input :type
end
```

As to whether or not the entire list can be read-only and still drop-down, the only solutions I see from google involve JS, for example:

http://techeyes.blogspot.com/2007/11/making-html-select-readonly.html

Comment: The example in link provides a solution. But I can not find the js code attached and therefore could not figure out how it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Is there more rail-ish solution?